# AutoMapper cannot find dll

Tags: automapper

I am building windows phone 8 and when I try to install AutoMapper Package, I got these errors:

```
PM> Install-Package AutoMapper
Installing 'AutoMapper 3.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'AutoMapper 3.1.0'.
Adding 'AutoMapper 3.1.0' to AutoMapper.
Successfully added 'AutoMapper 3.1.0' to AutoMapper.
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectMetadataElement] doesn't contain a method named 'Where'.
At C:\users\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\AutoMapper\packages\AutoMapper.3.1.0\tools\wp8\Install.ps1:14 
char:3
+         $refPath = $platformSpecificRef.Metadata.Where({ $_.Name -eq "HintPath" }).Val ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Exception calling "AddItem" with "2" argument(s): "Parameter "include" cannot have zero length."
At C:\users\miniesoft limited\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\AutoMapper\packages\AutoMapper.3.1.0\tools\wp8\Install.ps1:16 
char:3
+         $item = $msbuild.Xml.AddItem("Content", $refPath)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\users\miniesoft limited\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\AutoMapper\packages\AutoMapper.3.1.0\tools\wp8\Install.ps1:17 
char:3
+         $item.AddMetadata("Link", [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($refPath))
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\users\miniesoft limited\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\AutoMapper\packages\AutoMapper.3.1.0\tools\wp8\Install.ps1:18 
char:3
+         $item.AddMetadata("CopyToOutputDirectory", "PreserveNewest")
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The app can't run, any ideas?

Comment: It seems like a folder path is null in the install.ps1 PowerShell script. Might be a bug in their install code, although that is quite surprising!

Comment: Couple of questions - what version/edition of Visual Studio, and what version of NuGet do you have?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 Professional Update 3, Package Manager Console Host Version 2.7.40808.167. It's the latest Nuget because I can't update it.

Comment: I found the offending line, I'm not sure why it's not working for you. I can switch to an alternate method, I'll update tomorrow with a prerelease for you to try, if you don't mind! Can you open a GitHub issue for this, too? That would let other folks know if they run into this that it gets fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Created a GitHub issue here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/418 and a pre-release NuGet package here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/3.1.1-ci1000 if you can let me know if this work for you I'll push a 3.1.1 patch release. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jimmy, the installation succeeded but I can't run the application:   The error is: 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx}\Install\AutoMapper.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Comment: Well, one step better. Is that the full exception?

Comment: 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{XXXXXXX}\Install\AutoMapper.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[3052] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: The package is " Successfully installed 'AutoMapper 3.1.0'. Adding 'AutoMapper 3.1.0' to AutoMapper" before, but throw red warnings, App quit when starting to launch. Now I still can't run the wp8 app, can't hit App() constructor, the errors are still the same, can't find dll.

Comment: I just cannot reproduce this one. Do you think it would be possible to upload a sample solution showing this issue?